# JFET - transconductance, gain (μ), and internal resistance at the drain

Tags: gain, jfet, internal-resistance, transconductance

[image]

Here is an assignment: to determine gm, internal resistance at the drain, and maximum gain (μ).

1. Can transconductance gm be found from the formulas and graph?
2. How to determine graphically the internal resistance at the drain? As I understand it, it is: r'ds = delta V(DS)/delta I(D). How to determine the delta V(DS) from the graph?
3. In the end it is: A(v) = gm*r'ds. But how to determine μ with the given data?

Comment: Resistance should be voltage divided by current. So it can't be \$\Delta V_{ds}/\Delta V_{gs}\$.

Answer (score 1):

MU at 6 volts drain is just [Id(Vgs = 0.6v) - Id(Vgs = 0.2v)] / (0.6v - 0.2v), or

(13.5ma - 6.5ma) / 0.4v =  7ma/0.4 = 7ma*2.5 = 17.5mA/volt

Comment: but this is the calculation of gm (transconductance), not mu (gain)

Comment: gm and rd are Norton's equivalent. Mu is what you get if you turn it into Thevenin's one i.e. mu=gm*rd

Comment: yes, mu = gm*rd. But "[Id(Vgs = 0.6v) - Id(Vgs = 0.2v)] / (0.6v - 0.2v), or

(13.5ma - 6.5ma) / 0.4v = 7ma/0.4 = 7ma*2.5 = 17.5mA/volt"
- is the clear calculation of gm. delta Id / delta Vgs